# How does (declare (indent *)) work?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The info page doesn't mention this declaration. I found uses where it is set to either 1, 2 or 3, but what other options are possible? What exactly does it do?

On the surface of it, it looks like the digit means the number of lines after the macro name to indent further right, but in that case, how do I tell it to indent all forms as the first one?

Examples:

`(declare (indent 1))` does this:

```
(-iter 
    (with (a b c))
  (for i from 0 to 5)
  (collect i)
  (message "i: %s" i))
```

`(declare (indent 2))` does this:

```
(-iter 
    (with (a b c))
    (for i from 0 to 5)
  (collect i)
  (message "i: %s" i))
```

`(declare (indent 256))` (or just any large enough number) does this:

```
(-iter 
    (with (a b c))
    (for i from 0 to 5)
    (collect i)
    (message "i: %s" i))
```

I would like to do the last one, except for providing an arbitrary large number. Is there any way to tell "all" or some thing to that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indenting-Macros.html):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Indenting Macros` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Linked to from the index entry for `declare`, FYI. (Emacs 24.2.1)

Comment: A documentation link is nice and good but alone makes a poor answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question, and the manual is fairly obtuse, let me point to [this blog](https://oremacs.com/2015/01/28/notes-on-elisp-indentation/) which reveals that a value of `0` actually works here, and is synonymous to `defun`.

However, the indentation level does not go as far as with a number. Examine:

With `(indent nil)` or without an `(indent ...)` declaration:

```
(-iter
 (with (a b c))
 (for i from 0  to 5)
 (collect i)
 (message "i: %s" i))
```

With `(indent defun)` or `(indent 0)`:

```
(-iter
  (with (a b c))
  (for i from 0 to 5)
  (collect i)
  (message "i: %s" i))
```

With `(indent 256)`:

```
(-iter
    (with (a b c))
    (for i from 0 to 5)
    (collect i)
    (message "i: %s" i))
```

With `(indent (lambda (x y) 4))` you get the same result as for `(indent 256)`. Hardcoding an indent probably conflicts slightly with the mechanisms for specifying different indentation styles with `lisp-indent-function`, though.

Comment: `(declare (indent 0))` and `(declare (indent defun))` are definitely not equivalent.

Comment: @phils Can you clarify how they differ, or at least provide an example?

Comment: With `(defmacro foo (&rest args) (declare (indent defun)))` and `(defmacro bar (&rest args) (declare (indent 0)))`, compare `(foo arg body)` vs `(bar arg body)` where the first newline is following `arg`.

Comment: None of the examples in your answer put any of the macro arguments on the first line (i.e. immediately following `-iter`), which rather negates one of the main intentions of supplying a number to the `indent` declaration.

Comment: (n.b. I realise now that the example code is all from the question, and if we're *only* considering code written that way then I concur that `defun` and `0` would produce the same effect; my comment was pointing out that they are not equivalent *generally*; but maybe that's not as relevant here as I first though.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments; I'm afraid my understanding of this facility is still way less than perfect.